# WebView doesn't return control to app

Tags: android, webview

I was wondering if anyone knew how to return control back to an app after launching a webview? I got the example code for the webview from the android developers page but I haven't been able to find a way to return control to the app after getting out of webview. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class LaunchWeb extends Activity{
 WebView webView; 
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceType)
  { 
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceType); 
   setContentView(R.layout.webview_layout); 
   webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
   //webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());    
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webView.loadUrl(getIntent().getExtras().getString("url")); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "return control to the app?"  If the user hits back on the webview it should go back to your app.  What else are you looking for?

Comment: Yes, I mean when the user hits back button on the emulator it should go back to my app. Right now it doesn't do anything if I hit back. Also I should make it clear that its a basic webview like in example here: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

Comment: okay I just tried it again and it seems to be working but not quite to elegant. If I hit back button on the emulator (first time) it makes the webview appear white, if I hit it again (second time) it goes all black on me and, if I hit it again (third time) takes me back to the app. Now I guess my question changes to if there is a one click approach to above behavior.

Comment: Does that happen if you just open the webview, do nothing else, and then hit back?  It could take multiple back presses if you have done things in the webview.  Otherwise, show us how you are launching the webview.

Comment: It happens when I just open webview. I haven't added any other behaviors yet. Here is the code of how I instantiate the webview 
public class LaunchWeb extends Activity{
 WebView webView;
 
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceType){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceType);
  setContentView(R.layout.webview_layout);
  
  webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
  //webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webView.loadUrl(getIntent().getExtras().getString("url"));
 }
}

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are not looking at a `WebView`, most likely.

Run your app. When you get to the page you think you are viewing in the `WebView`, click the MENU button. You will probably see the options menu of the Browser application show up. That's because you are in the Browser application, not your application.

`WebView`, by default, launches all clicks on links *and all redirects* into the user's choice of browser. You are probably being caught by the redirect scenario -- the URL you supplied to `loadUrl()` triggered a redirect on the server, and the redirected URL is being loaded by the browser, not by the `WebView`.

You will need to attach a `WebViewClient` object to the `WebView`, and implement `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` in the `WebViewClient`, to indicate which links/redirects should be loaded into the `WebView` and which should be loaded in the user's choice of browser.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments it feels like you have a browsing history.

If you built an activity with a webview, you should try to clear the historyStack so when you press back it will return.

You can even set that in a WebViewClient. On each page load you clear the history.

```
    WebView webview = new WebView(mContext);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new AuthClient());

    private class AuthClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView v, String url) {
                v.clearHistory();
            }
     }
```